# Vertices-dependent centroid construction

Tags: modeling, mesh, geometry

I'm very new to Blender so this question may be very simple / foolish, but I don't find the way.

Suppose I want to construct (draw? add to mesh?) the centroid of a triangle (the middle point together with the three medians) in a way that it dynamically changes when the three original vertices are grabbed and the triangle itself is not deformed (if I add points and edges with the knife, the triangle deforms to a polygon when the vertices are moved). Could this be done? Which are the best tools for it? My goal is to do an animation showing the centroid of a triangle whose vertices are moving. Thanks!!

Comment: can you add a picture or diagram of what you want, I'm having a hard time flowing what you want to achieve.

Comment: @David Thanks. Suppose I want something like http://mathifold.org/en/applet_centroid.html, that is, by moving one vertex, the whole construction changes.

Comment: Would Proportional editing work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Subsurf Modifier

You can surely set up your own rigging system, but if you don't need to extremely custumize your animation, fastest way to show the position of the centroid is taking advantage of the **[Subdivison Surface Modifier](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/modifiers/generate/subsurf.html)** with **Simple** type enabled in oder to see the medians meeting in the middle.

[image]

### Drivers

In alternative, I would suggest to **[Hook](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/modifiers/deform/hooks.html)** the vertices of a **[Poly Curve](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/curves/editing/introduction.html?#converting-curve-type)** (the triangle) to three Empties and use **[Drivers](https://www.blender.org/manual/animation/drivers.html)** to control the location of a fourth object (the centroid). This way you should be able to customize almost everything in your scene (the triangle section, the presence of mendian lines, the shape of the centroid individuator..)

[image]

For each coordinate you should assing a value coming from a scripted expression capable of giving the [Average mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Average) of the other empties coordinate relative to the considered axis.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks!! The SubSurf modifier sems very good, but unfortunately I don't get the inner lines (neither in Calmut-Clark; there I get an hexagon only). I'm working with Blender 2.76, that's not the problem, is it? I'll try the other things in the meanwhile

Comment: In wich sense you "don't get" the inner lines? It's ok if you can't select them, because the modifier isn't applied (that's where the "interactivity" trick comes from"), but they should be visible like in my iage sequence.

Comment: There's no change when 'simple' is chosen... I mean, nothing drawn. It's a pity I cannot attach a picture... However, the Drivers method also seems very good, and able to generalise to other similar aspects... thank you very much!!

Comment: You're welcome! Maybe you have "Optimal display" or "Adjust edit cage.." option enabled. You can post the link to a picture in the comments after uploading to something like imgur.

Comment: How have you snapped / linked the triangle to the three empties? I can't get 'A', 'B' and 'C', objects to which I can refer separatedly, together with a triangle joining them. Or also... if I have a face, how can I refer to a precise vertex (for instance to take its x coordinate)?

Comment: You'll have to select a control point of the curve and run "Hook to New object", or use the modifier: see https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/modifiers/deform/hooks.html. What do you mean by "refer to a precise vertex"? I dont' get the context of your second question.